# How to cast enums?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, casting

I have a third-party unscoped enum (that I can't modify) that I'd really like to cast to my own scoped enum. How can I provide something like a conversion operator?

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
enum ThirdPartyLetter {
  A=4,
  B=5
};

enum class MyNumber {
  ONE=1,
  TWO=2

  // This doesn't compile, of course
  /*Number(const ThirdPartyLetter& rhs) {
    if(rhs == ThirdPartyLetter::A) {
      return ONE;
    }
    else {
      return TWO;
    }
  }*/
};


int main() {
  ThirdPartyLetter letter = ThirdPartyLetter::A;
  MyNumber number = static_cast<MyNumber>(letter);
  // Without the cast, this prints 4 (an invalid enum value!)
  std::cout << int(number) << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way to provide some kind of casting from `ThirdPartyNumber` to `MyNumber`?

Comment: What was the output you were expecting with your cast ?

Comment: Well, I'd like the cast to convert ThirdPartyLetter::A to MyNumber::ONE, and ThirdPartyLetter::B to MyNumber::TWO. So my expected output would be 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An idiomatic way to do that at compile-time in C++ is using traits.
As an example:

```
enum Foo { ONE, TWO };
enum Bar { THREE, FOUR };

template<Foo> struct conv;
template<> struct conv<Foo::ONE> { static constexpr Bar value = Bar::THREE; };
template<> struct conv<Foo::TWO> { static constexpr Bar value = Bar::FOUR; };
```

If you want to do that at runtime, maybe a switch is well suited.
Anyway, you can still use traits to centralize your conversion logic and do something like this:

```
Bar get(Foo choice) {
    switch(choice) {
    case Foo::ONE:
        return conv<ONE>::value;
     case Foo::TWO:
        return conv<TWO>::value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is using traits better than just doing `case Foo::ONE: return Bar::THREE`?

Comment: @ThomasJohnson Usually, if you have more than one point where you work with those enums, each change in the conversion logic will require you to modify all those pieces of code. In this case, traits act like a centralized definition on top of which you can write your code.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense

Comment: Why using struct with inner value instead of template variable?

Comment: That's another solution. You can post an answer with it.